# All of you who like

Tags: grammatical-number, articles

I want to say "I hope all of you who like winter is happier now"
Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I hope **those** of you who like winter **are** happier now"

Comment: Why did you change _all_ to _those_? That completely changes the meaning of the sentence.